# Time Machine is filling up my backup disk

Tags: backup

I have been backing up my Mac with Time Machine on a daily basis for a couple of years now, but I notice that, on my Mac, I have 766GB available of 1TB, but on my Seagate backup drive, it shows only 86GB available of 750GB.

Can someone tell me why it is increasing so much and what happens when it gets full? Can I delete everything and start again?

Surely the back overwrites the data and not add more to it. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. That's the way Time Machine is supposed to work: Time Machine will back up your Mac until the backup disk is full.  See https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/if-the-time-machine-backup-disk-is-full-mh15137/mac for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You paid for a 750 GB backup drive, so Time Machine uses all the storage on it. If you used it for say 5 years, and you still have 86GB free, then every version of every file that ever was on your Mac is still in your Time Machine backup somewhere.

When all the empty space is gone, Time Machine will delete the oldest backups until there is enough space for the next backup, and from then on your backup drive will always stay almost full. So you can restore older files for many years.

Answer (score 0):

`Time Machine` maintains a complete record over time. When you delete something on your HDD/SSD it's gone there, and the space is freed up. But on `Time Machine`, the deleted files are retained. Why? Well - imagine you deleted those files accidentally... you'd expect `Time Machine` to cover that error. And so it does.

At some point, `Time Machine` will begin deleting older records when it detects that you are about to run out of space on your backup drive. That may be happening now on your 750GB drive.